# Track Config Files in Source Control and Deploy from CI

Tags: deployment, version-control, hudson, configuration-files

As many apps do, we have a number of config and properties files for our Java applications.  We have gone with the approach of keeping these files separate from our codebase (i.e. they are not included in the war files for deployment) but in a separate directory.  However, I would still like to track changes to these files in a source control and deploy them using our CI.

I'm looking for strategies on how others have done this.  Did you write a script to push the files to the app server(s).  Does the script live on the CI server?

Our SCM is Mercurial which we have set up on its own server to use as a central repo.  Our CI is Hudson (not Jenkins) set up on its own server and of course our app servers are separate from these as well.  All servers are *nix OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using configuration management tools like [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) for managing all your application configuration files. Both tools use "manifests" or "receipes" which can placed under revision control and matched to each server deploying the application.

Another option is to consider is to develop an install package for your OS, see the following articles for more details:

- http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/11/bringing-java-and-linux-together-on-the-way-to-continuous-live-deployment/

The advantage of doing it this way is that the install can be configured to generate the correct configuration tailored for the environment it is deployed onto. A more important benefit is that it's simpler to manage and install.

Comment: Thanks for the links to Chef and Puppet. I wasn't aware of them and am reading about them. The install package option at first glance seems like overkill for a few config files that aren't OS related.

Comment: Hi, I've spoken with some other teams in my company and it looks like some of them use CFEngine which we can piggy-back off of. I didn't know there were config management systems before. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!